# Plotting densities in R

Tags: r, plot, histogram

So, I am plotting densities (histograms). For example:

```
d <- density(table[table$position==2,]$rt)
```

But, I want to plot multiple densities on the same plot. For instance, I also want to plot

```
density(table[table$position==3,]$rt)
density(table[table$position==4,]$rt)
density(table[table$position==5,]$rt)
```

Furthermore, I want to specify the center point for each of these densities.

Another way to ask this question is, how can I manually shift a density plot over by a certain number of x units? (for instance, increase all x values by 5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As with many R analysis functions,  saving the output is your friend.  So is `?density`.

`foo<-density(something)`

`names(foo)`

`"x", "y" , "bw", "n" , "call" ,"data.name"`

So,
`plot(foo$x+5, foo$y, t='l')`
And you're done so far as I can tell.

Answer (score 4):

For the piece of your question about plotting multiple densities on the same plot, use `lines`:

```
dat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100) + 2, z = rnorm(100) + 5)

plot(c(-2.5,8),c(0,0.5),type = "n")
lines(density(dat$x))
lines(density(dat$y))
lines(density(dat$z))
```

You open an empty plotting device using `plot(...,type = "n")` and then draw on it using `lines` or `points`, etc.

[image]

Comment: Good point -- I should have stated specifically that over-plotting is best done using `lines()`