# Plotting densities from a table in R

Tags: r

I'm currently trying to plot densities from a table/list where column 1 is just the names/labels of the data and column 2 is the actual numbers I want plotted.

If I just have a file of numbers, I can get my code to work using the scan function.  However when I have my table, I get a `argument 'x' must be numeric` error.

Here is my code:

```
library(gplots)
dataLine = read.table("fileLocation")

den = density(dataLine)

plot(den, col = "red", ylim = c(0, 50), xlim = c(0.045,1))
```

Should I be using something like what this previous question has done with selecting for a specific column? [Plotting densities in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604838/plotting-densities-in-r#).

i.e. should I have change my code to be `d <- density(table[dataLine$position==2,]$rt)`?

Because that gives me an error saying `object of type'closure' is not subsettable`

Any suggestions on what I should do to plot my column of numbers? Apologies if my code doesn't make sense; I'm fairly new to R

Comment: I don't think you need gplots for anything. Can you post the output to `den`? Note how `plot(density(1:10))` works fine.

Comment: @SeñorO for `den = density(dataLine)` my output is `Error in density.default(dataLine) : argument 'x' must be numeric`

Comment: So the problem is the format of dataline, not in the plotting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your dataline object is a data frame with multiple columns, you need to pass only the column of data to the `density` function.  To pass the 2nd column of the data frame you can do this:

```
density(dataline[[2]])
```

See the help page `?'[['` for more options to use just part of a data frame.